# How to generate a transaction with ethers setting a Paymaster to pay for the gas fees?

Tags: ethers.js, smart-contract-wallets, erc-4337, account-abstraction, paymaster

I want to generate a simple transaction from a Smart Wallet (Account Abstraction - ERC4337) but I also want to pay for gas fees on behalf of the user.

By looking at the `UserOperation` struct...

```
struct UserOperation {
    address sender;
    uint256 nonce;
    bytes initCode;
    bytes callData;
    uint256 callGasLimit;
    uint256 verificationGasLimit;
    uint256 preVerificationGas;
    uint256 maxFeePerGas;
    uint256 maxPriorityFeePerGas;
    bytes paymasterAndData;
    bytes signature;
}
```

...I understand that I have to set `paymasterAndData` up in order to be able to sponsor transactions. How can I do that when I create the `UserOperation` using `ethers`?